# When to close connection to signaling server in webrtc?

Tags: webrtc

Can we close the websocket connection to signaling server as soon as the peer to peer stream is established in webrtc, or the connection to the signaling server has to be maintained for the whole period of video chat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You typically want to keep the connection. Consider what happens when the peer-to-peer connection is lost and you need to do an ice restart and exchange new candidates.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but wouldn’t it be more efficient if we close the connection and reopen it if we need ice restart?

Comment: If both peers are disconnected you wouldn't be able to push your SDP all the way across (since the other side is disconnected from signaling). You could reconnect each side when ICE enters disconnected/failed, but that will add latency.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't sever any ties to a signalling channel. As @Philipp Hancke said, if all SCTP or SRTP connection is lost, and you need an ICE restart, then no peer will be able to send the ICE restart signal to each other.

However, if you are a peer-to-peer purist, as long as there are more than two participants in a peer-to-peer network, you can sever the connection to the signalling server, and instead opt to use one of the other peers as a signalling channel.

If all signalling connection is lost, then you will have to re-establish a signalling connection first before ICE restart, which could add to latency.